# If I open a text file in append mode, can I find out what line number I'm on?

Tags: python, io

What I want to do is something like:

```
with open(textfile, 'at') as f:
    f.write(f'{current_line_number}: ' + "Some text" + '\n')
```

Comment: Simple answer - no. There's no "magic" way of counting the lines in file other than by reading and counting them one at a time or reading the entire file into memory and counting the occurrences of line separators

Comment: Files are just streams of byes. The file system stores the *size* of the file, which allows you to efficiently move the file pointer of an open file to the *end* of the file without scanning the entire file linearly. Finding the special characters (linefeeds or linefeed/carriage-return pairs) that define lines *does* require scanning the entire file.

Answer (score 3):

You can open the file with 'r+' (read and write mode), and then you can get a list of lines by using the `readlines()` and count how many lines the list has with `len()`, then just add +1 to the result: `len(f.readlines()) + 1` and you got how many lines the file has. Something like this:

```
with open(textfile, 'r+') as f:
    current_line_number = len(f.readlines()) + 1
    f.write(f'{current_line_number}: ' + "Some text" + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `open` function in append mode, (`'a+'`). If you want to open a text file exclusively in append mode, you can also use this code and `file.seek` which moves your pointer in the file to the start. At the end of your code, this with statement should simply close the file after execution.

```
with open('file.txt', 'a+') as file:
     file.seek(0)                     
     line_number = len(file.readlines())
     file.write('your new line\n')
```